# BaseX - insert node {...} into //.. for multiple nodes

Tags: iteration, xquery, nodes, basex

I am currently facing a problem with the BaseX native XML-Database.

I have got a sample dataset where I want to check whether a certain attribute in a certain node exists and if it does then set a value "true". If it doesn't exist I want to insert a new attribute. This is my code for a single Node:

```
if(fn:exists(//Dataset[@attribute="2"]/@b)) then
  replace value of node //Dataset[@attribute="2"]/@b with "true"
else
  insert node (attribute { 'b' } { "CREATED!" }) into //Dataset[@attribute="2"]
```

The problem I am facing at the moment is that I cannot find a way of iterating through all nodes of the type "Dataset" for example and check every single node.. It always says "Single element or document expected as insert target".

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> Okay, Googled for a long time but 15 minutes more would have saved me from posting this question:

```
for $dataset in //mondial/Dataset
 let $DOCH := $dataset/@DOCH
 return
 if(fn:exists($DOCH)) then (
replace value of node $DOCH with "true")
else (
  insert node (attribute DOCH {"true"}) into $dataset)
```